# Reducer that can be re-used in different branches of the same Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I wonder if there's any established pattern of having a reducer that can be re-used in different branches of the same global Redux state?

Typical example would be pagination. Every table grid has same params, like: `data`, `pageNumber`, `pageSize`, `sortBy`, `sortOrder`, `filters`, etc. It doesn't make sense to have a separate reducer (and set of corresponding actions as well) for every page that has grid in it. There should be a way to have just one and be able to re-use it wherever required.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  What you are describing sounds like what Redux was designed for.  Is this what you are looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/lm57klz7z?file=/src/App.js?  If not, please provide some example code of your problem.

Comment: From what I see your example has all products pre-fetched and hits the backend only with search keyword. I'm talking about the case when you fetch only data specific to a certain page and offset. So you actually need to send all params to the backend and you need to keep them all in redux state.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work we've created a fragment concept. For example, we have a searchFragment, which have actions to filter data. In this case, we've created the following actions:

- `createSearchFragmentActions`: Responsible to create a set of actions with a prefix sent as an argument.
- `createSearchFragmentReducer`: Responsible to create a sub-reducer with the name sent as an argument and deal with the actions dispatched.
- `createSearchFragmentSelectors`: If you use `reselect`, this function basically returns a set of selectors to filter the subreducer created.

Comment: That's exactly what I implemented (with prefix and even naming of function almost exactly like that :D), but I thought it's kind of clunky, so was looking if there's a better way. Also I didn't manage to typesafe it properly in TypeScript. Did you?

Comment: No =/ We implemented this without having TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a standard Redux pattern known as [a "higher-order reducer"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic).